# Jquery each loop output when calling ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need some help with my jquery code as I have got a problem with output for each element from the PHP array when calling ajax function. I have stored the list of elements in the PHP array and I would like to output each element in the jquery loop using ajax but I am unable to do so.

When I try this:

```
var data = result.data.attachment;

for (var i = 1, len = data[i].length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(data.filename);
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
var data = result.data.attachment;

for (var i = 1, len = data[i].length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(data[i].filename);
}
```

Output for readDraft.php attachment:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
      (
         [is_attachment] => 1
         [filename] => draft_attachment.rar
         [attachment] =>
      )
)


Array
(
    [2] => Array
      (
         [is_attachment] => 1
         [filename] => draft_attachment - Copy.rar
         [attachment] =>
      )
)
```

Here is the full jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click','#openDraft', function(e) {

    $.ajax({
    url: 'readDraft.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {
        email_number: email_number
    },
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result.data.attachment);            

        var data = result.data.attachment;

        for (var i = 1, len = data[i].length; i < len; i++) {
            alert(data.filename);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the full code for readDraft.php:

```
<?php

$structure = imap_fetchstructure($draft, $email_number);
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($draft, $email_number);
$draft_from = $overview[0]->from;
$draft_to = $overview[0]->to;
$draft_subject = utf8_decode(imap_utf8($overview[0]->subject));
$draft_fulldate = $overview[0]->date;
$draft_date = convDate($draft_fulldate);
$draft_message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($draft, $email_number, 1.2));
$attachments = array();

if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

    for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

        if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
            foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                    $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                    $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                }
            }
        }

        if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
            foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                    $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                    $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                }
            }
        }

        if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
            $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($connection, $message_number, $i+1);
            if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
            }
            elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
            }
        }
    }
}

$data = array("receipt"=>$draft_to, "subject"=>$draft_subject, "encryption"=>$email_number_encrypt, "message"=>$draft_message, "attachment"=>$attachments);
$response = array("data"=>$data, "success"=>"successfully", "total_inbox"=>$total_inbox_unread, "total_spam"=>$total_spam_unread);
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Here is the console log:

```
1: {filename: "draft_attachment.rar"}
2: {filename: "draft_attachment - Copy.rar"}
```

What happens is when I'm calling the ajax function, there is no alert display so there is something wrong. What I'm expecting to do is when I am calling ajax function, I want to set the alert to display for each filename using the index value.

Can you please show me an example how I could output for each filename using the index value when I am using ajax function?

Thank you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There is no error as I have checked it. I have also checked on `alert(result.data.attachment[1].filename);` and `alert(result.data.attachment[2].filename);` so I get `draft_attachment.rar` and `draft_attachment - Copy.rar` as a return string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So how I can use the loop display the alert for the filename?

Comment: *"Here is the console log:"* There is no `console.log` in the quoted code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added `console.log` in the quoted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Array indexes start at 0, not 1; and
2. It doesn't make sense to use `data[i].length` for `len` in `for (var i = 1, len = data[i].length; i < len; i++) {`
3. `alert(data.filename);` accesses `filename` on `data`, not `data[i]`.

You probably want:

```
success: function(result) {
    var data = result.data.attachment;

    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    // 0, not 1--^            ^
    // No [i] here ----------/
        alert(data[i].filename);
    // [i] here-- ^^^
    }
}
```

Or with a vaguely-modern JavaScript engine:

```
success: function(result) {
    result.data.attachment.forEach(function(entry) {
        alert(entry.filename);
    });
}
```

Or with an ES2015+ JavaScript engine:

```
success: function(result) {
    for (const entry of result.data.attachment) {
        alert(entry.filename);
    }
}
```

---

In a comment, you've said that when you output `result.data.attachment`, you see:

```
1: {filename: "draft_attachment.rar"}
2: {filename: "draft_attachment - Copy.rar"}
```

That tells us that what you have isn't an array, it's an object. Your best bet is to correct the PHP code so it gets serialized to a proper array. But if for any reason you can't do that, you can do this:

```
success: function(result) {
    var data = result.data.attachment;
    var i = 1;
    while (data[i]) {
        alert(data[i].filename);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: ,Crowder Thank you very much for this, I have tried the first one, no alert display. I have tried the second one, there is an error: `result.data.attachment.forEach is not a function` and the third one there is an error: `result.data.attachment is not iterable`.

Comment: @RobertJones - That tells us that `result.data.attachment` is not an array. Only debugging can tell you how to go forward from there.

Comment: Actually you are correct. I have checked `console.log(result.data.attachment);` and here is the answer: `1: {filename: "draft_attachment.rar"}
2: {filename: "draft_attachment - Copy.rar"}`

Comment: @RobertJones - Added to the end of the answer. Sorry, I don't do enough PHP to be able to tell you how to update the PHP code so that what gets output is an array.